# REDIS. Is it possible to create insertion-ordered list-set?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to create insertion-ordered list-set in redis?

**Example:**

fill data:

```
push("listname", "x")
push("listname", "y")
push("listname", "x")
```

desired result:

```
get_list("listname") => ["x", "y"]
```

We need to do it in distributed system, so ordered set (ZADD) is not applicable as is, because we cannot guarantee score order.

Comment: The usual way to do this would be to use sorted sets where the score is a timestamp. Can you expand on what you mean by "we cannot guarantee score order"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using both SET and LIST data structures combining LUA scripting?

```
EVAL "if redis.call('SADD', KEYS[2], ARGV[1]) == 1 then return redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) else return 0 end" 2 listname setname value
```

Example:

```
> EVAL "if redis.call('SADD', KEYS[2], ARGV[1]) == 1 then return redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) else return 0 end" 2 list set x
(integer) 1

> EVAL "if redis.call('SADD', KEYS[2], ARGV[1]) == 1 then return redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) else return 0 end" 2 list set y
(integer) 2

> EVAL "if redis.call('SADD', KEYS[2], ARGV[1]) == 1 then return redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) else return 0 end" 2 list set x
(integer) 0

> LRANGE list 0 -1
1) "x"
2) "y"
```